# Printing a node in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, printing, javafx-8

So I have a simple tab which contains few grid panes. After u chose a name from a ListView, data from database is displayed on the right side( check the link of my gui ). There is a button with a text "Stampaj" on it, in english  "Print". When it's pressed it prints the right side of the tab (grid pane with data). My program is printing what i want but it does not print it propertly( check the link after printing).

Link of my gui (tab): https://postimg.org/image/bmtwbhxv5/

Link of data after printing( in pdf): https://postimg.org/image/elp9ugvlt/

Code of the method I print my node with:

```
public void print(final Node node) {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter().getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout =
        printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.EQUAL);
    JobSettings jobSettings = job.getJobSettings();
    jobSettings.setPageLayout(pageLayout);
    boolean printed = job.printPage(node);
    if (printed) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Now when I call this method, the argument I forward is GridPane which contains Labels and other components that are relavent to that data showing ( right side of GUI ). I've tryed to switch places with those GridPanes I have at my current tab and then it prints propertly ( from the start of the page ). I know why is he printing like this but I'm wondering is there a way to move that text to the start of the page and print it normaly without switching places and leaving my GUI the way it is?

Comment: You may find this usefull https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-example-javafx-8

Comment: I know about that article, I've tryed it, but it also resize font at my GUI if I remember corectly and still prints the same (only with bigger font now).

Answer (score 0):

How are you laying out the GridPanes? It looks like you might be setting properties on your GridPane that shift it over to the right on screen, translateX or layoutX, which is why it prints properly when you move it to the left in the UI.

When you send it to the printer it still has those properties set so it's moving it over on the page. You could either reset those properties on the GridPane before printing, or alter your view to use another container for the GridPanes so you don't need to set them in the first place, like an HBox or SplitPane.